# Is it possible to get more than one balloon on map in android application?

Tags: android, google-maps

Is it possible to get more than one balloon on map in android application?How could someone help?I am new at this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used this project for multiple place markers you can too.

Just take a look at [this.](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: Those balloons are called infoWindows, and Yes, it's possible to have more than 1!

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#InfoWindows

And this is a great example!:

http://you.arenot.me/2010/06/29/google-maps-api-v3-0-multiple-markers-multiple-infowindows/

Answer (score 0):

I think your using [this project](https://github.com/galex/android-mapviewballoons/tree/master/android-mapviewballoons)

Adding an additional balloon is as easy as adding an extra item to the ItemizedOverlay collection.

```
    mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();

    // first overlay
    drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker);
     itemizedOverlay = new MyItemizedOverlay(drawable, mapView);


    GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)(51.5174723*1E6),(int)(-0.0899537*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(point, "Tomorrow Never Dies (1997)", 
            "(M gives Bond his mission in Daimler car)");
    itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem);

    GeoPoint point2 = new GeoPoint((int)(51.515259*1E6),(int)(-0.086623*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayItem2 = new OverlayItem(point2, "GoldenEye (1995)", 
            "(Interiors Russian defence ministry council chambers in St Petersburg)");      
    itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem2);

    mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);
```